# No 'ack' header in MESSAGE frame

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp, subscriber

I have a subscription client that subscribes to a topic (not a queue) on **ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.16.2** via STOMP. In order to manually acknowledge `MESSAGE` frames using the `ACK` frame to the message broker, the client passes `ack:client` in a `SUBSCRIBE` frame. But when `MESSAGE` frames are received in the client, there is no `ack` header available in them. Why?
Is there some configuration missing?

Comment: Can you turn on [STOMP debug logging](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp#debugging), reproduce the problem, and add the logs to your question?

Comment: Because `ack` wasn't available in a `MESSAGE` frame, I happen to try with `message-id`  to acknowledge instead and it appears to be working. I am not sure if this is implementation specific in ActiveMQ Classic. But I could not find any information regarding this in online doc.

Comment: I tried to upload the logs but the number of chars in comments are limited. Is there a way to upload a large text?

Comment: I sent 
`ACK
message-id:ID:mi202110-50648-1687540697462-63:1:1:1:1`

instead of 
`ACK
ack:????`

Comment: Provide more details in your original question, what client?  what stomp version?  what are you seeing vs what are you expecting etc.

Comment: Use https://pastebin.com if the log is too long to post here. Paste there, link here.

Comment: It's important to know exactly which version of STOMP you're using (e.g. 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2) as the behavior of the `ACK` frame is different between versions. It may be that what you're seeing is expected.

Comment: Thanks Justin and Tim for your comments.  As you pointed out the version of STOMP, I found that the broker is using version **1.0** and the version support `message-id` to acknowledge `MESSAGE` frames. Also there are only two types of ack mode - `auto` and `client`.

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.16.2 supports STOMP 1.0,1.1 and 1.2 so most likely your client simply isn't requesting the version.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's good to know that there is a way to use a specific version of STOMP.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `MESSAGE` and `ACK` frames are slightly different among different versions of STOMP. Once the client sends the `CONNECT` frame with `accept-version:1.2` option, all worked fine.